# Asp.net 4.0 SQLServer 2008 hosting in the UK

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have just finished my own web app and I am looking at which is the best UK based web hosting   solution?  I would be grateful for any input as I am finding it very difficult to cut through the cr*p.
Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's really for this site, as it's not directly programming per se...

Anyway, I use [Hosting UK](http://www.hostinguk.net) for my web hosting, .NET 4.0 and SQL 2008 databases are all available, and a medium trust environment so you can include other binaries in your application.

I've also found their support to be very good.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm just finding it very difficult to navigate through the dross and to see which one is actually any good.

Answer (score 0):

We host with [NimbusHosting](http://www.nimbushosting.co.uk) and are extremely pleased with their service. They offer VPS packages, both Windows and Linux.

We currently only use Linux, so I unfortunately cannot verify what edition of SQL Server they allow (most likely Express).

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure if they host asp.net though.  Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: They do host .NET applications :) The windows servers come with SL Server and IIS.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check them out.